# Finding lowest eigenvalues and its eigenvector by Arnoldi method does not work correctly

Tags: matrix

As far as I know, the Lanczos method (`Method-> Arnoldi`) gives a ground state (an eigenvector according to  the eigenvalue with the lowest value) of a matrix. But Mathematica gives another result:

```
d = DiagonalMatrix[{1, 0.8, -1, 2}];
t = Orthogonalize[{{1, 2, 0, 1}, {0, 3, 2, -2}, {1, 0, 4, -1}, {0, 1,0, 1}}];
 m = t . d . Transpose[t];

Eigenvalues[m, -1, Method -> "Arnoldi"]
0.8

Eigenvalues[m, 1, Method -> "Arnoldi"]
2.0
```

While we know that eigenvalues are:

```
{2.0, 1.0, -1.0, 0.8}
```

How really can we access to `-1.0` and its corresponding eigenvector!!!

Comment: The documentation says: ``Eigenvalues[m,-k]`` _gives the k that are **smallest in absolute value**._

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Weird indeed. This seems to work, though:

```
Eigenvalues[m, 1, Method -> {"Arnoldi", "Criteria" -> "RealPart"}]
-Eigenvalues[-m, 1, Method -> {"Arnoldi", "Criteria" -> "RealPart"}]
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is the setup.

```
d = DiagonalMatrix[{1, 0.8, -1, 2}];
t = Orthogonalize[{{1, 2, 0, 1}, {0, 3, 2, -2}, {1, 0, 4, -1}, {0, 1, 
     0, 1}}];
m = t . d . Transpose[t];
```

First find the largest eigenvalue in magnitude. (If it were negative we'd be done, but it's not.) To get the largest in magnitude negative eigenvalue we subtract a multiple of the identity matrix, using this as multiplier.

```
maxeig = Abs[First[Eigenvalues[m, 1]]]
maxnegeig = Eigenvalues[m - maxeig*IdentityMatrix[4], 1][[1]] + maxeig

Out[240]= 2.

Out[241]= -1.
```

If we also want the corresponding eigenvector we can instead do as below.

```
{val, eigvec} = Eigensystem[m - maxeig*IdentityMatrix[4], 1];
{val + maxeig, eigvec}

Out[246]= {{-1.}, {{-2.36309*10^-17, 0.528271, 0.784503, 0.324785}}}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. But I think this is not efficient for a larger matrix, since for a larger one, it needs calculate all eigenvectors!!!

Comment: @InzoBabaria I see Daniel computing only one eigenvalue or eigenpair at a time... No reason to start shouting.

Comment: Does the option `"Shift"` for `"Arnoldi"` method work the same way?

Comment: I don't recall offhand but it is plausible that "Shift" will allow you to isolate that eigenvalue.